# Postback checkbox asp.net com plugin Switchery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Estou montando uma lista de registros em uma tabela com asp.net. Crio para cada linha um checkbox para realizar uma ação através de postback toda vez que o checkbox for marcado ou desmarcado. Utilizo o plugin Switchery para estilizar esse checkbox, mas quando clico no switch (ação igual ao marcar/desmarcar a caixa do checkbox), ele não realiza o postback. Se eu comento a linha com a classe padrão utilizada pelo plugin ou mudo o nome da classe (assim deixando as checkboxes "cruas" na tabela) o postback funciona corretamente.

Código JS da criação do Switch

```
 var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));
            elems.forEach(function (html) { 
                var switchery = new Switchery(html); 
            });
```

Código C#

```
CheckBox lkBtnExcluir = new CheckBox();
                        lkBtnExcluir.ID = dr["empr_codigo"].ToString() + "_id"; 
                        lkBtnExcluir.AutoPostBack = true;
                        lkBtnExcluir.Attributes.Add("USUARIO", dr["COD_USUARIO"].ToString());
                        lkBtnExcluir.InputAttributes.Add("class", "js-switch");
                        //lkBtnExcluir.CssClass = "js-switch";

                        if (dr["usa_atend"].ToString() == "S")
                        {
                            lkBtnExcluir.Checked = true;
                            lkBtnExcluir.Attributes.Add("STATUS", "N"); 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lkBtnExcluir.Attributes.Add("STATUS", "S"); 
                        }

                        lkBtnExcluir.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(mudarStatus_click);
                        tdAcao_.Controls.Add(lkBtnExcluir);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui corrigir. Caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema que eu tive, segue um evento no *Javascript* para forçar o *PostBack*:

```
  <script>
  $(".js-switch").change(function () {
            __doPostBack($(this).attr("id"), '');
        });
  </script>
```